# iMessages no longer working after Yosemite upgrade

Tags: messages, macos

I just updated my MacBook Pro (Early 2011) to OS X Yosemite, now iMessages is no longer working. I turned it off/on on both my computer and my iPhone, reset my Keychain, and a bunch of other stuff. Nothing worked.

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an hour long call with Apple, I was finally told to reset my default Keychain, and after a reboot, that worked. We diagnosed this as the issue because every time I rebooted, iCloud/FaceTime/Messages would ask for my password again, even though it had supposedly saved it.

This also came right after I had just reset the default Keychain to solve not being able to connect to my wireless network.

Answer (score -2):

You'll just have to wait till iOS 8.1

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Please expand on your answer. Is there a specific bug being fixed in iOS 8.1 that resolves this issue? How do you know iOS 8.1 will fix the OP's issue?

Comment: This would be true for SMS, but the original question was about iMessages.